# Como dar merge em arquivo já minificado com grunt-contrib-uglify

Tags: javascript, node.js, front-end, grunt

A situação é a seguinte, estou usando o [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) para minificar os javascript do meu projeto em um único arquivo, o problema é que um desses arquivos já está minificado, e o **uglify** não adiciona ele no meu arquivo de destino, causando erro de sintaxe no projeto.

A pergunta seria, tem alguma forma de fazer o [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) pelo menos copiar o arquivo já minificado e juntar com os demais no arquivo final?

O código do meu `Gruntfile.js` é:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        skinPath: './skin/frontend/default/<%= pkg.name %>',
        cssmin: {
            combine: {
                files: {
                    '<%= skinPath %>/css/vendor.min.css': [
                        '<%= skinPath %>/css/bootstrap.css',
                        '<%= skinPath %>/css/bootstrap-responsive.css',
                        '<%= skinPath %>/magentothem/**/*.css'
                    ],
                    '<%= skinPath %>/css/styles.min.css': [
                        '<%= skinPath %>/css/styles.css',
                        '<%= skinPath %>/css/widgets.css',
                    ],
                    '<%= skinPath %>/css/print.min.css': [ '<%= skinPath %>/css/print.css' ],
                    '<%= skinPath %>/css/styles-ie.min.css': [ '<%= skinPath %>/css/styles-ie.css' ],
                    '<%= skinPath %>/css/styles-ie8.min.css': [ '<%= skinPath %>/css/styles-ie8.css' ],
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                preserveComments: 'all'
            },
            supimpa: {
                src: [
                    './js/prototype/prototype.js',
                    './js/lib/ccard.js',
                    './js/prototype/validation.js',
                    './js/scriptaculous/builder.js',
                    './js/scriptaculous/effects.js',
                    './js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js',
                    './js/scriptaculous/controls.js',
                    './js/scriptaculous/slider.js',
                    './js/varien/js.js',
                    './js/varien/form.js',
                    './js/varien/menu.js',
                    './js/mage/translate.js',
                    './js/mage/cookies.js',
                    './js/magentothem/ma.jq.slide.js'
                    './js/magentothem/ma.flexslider.js',
                    './js/magentothem/jquery-ui.js'
                ],
                dest: './js/supimpa.min.js'
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin', 'uglify']);

};
```

Sendo que `./js/magentothem/ma.jq.slide.js` já está minificado, e por causa disso como expliquei anteriormente não é adicionado no arquivo `./js/supimpa.min.js`.

Existe alguma opção ou método de fazer ele no minimo adicionar o código no arquivo final?

Comment: Faz alguma diferênça qual deles virá primeiro no ficheiro final?

Comment: Infelizmente faz sim, o arquivo `ma.jq.slide.js` contem o Jquery minificado junto com algumas alterações, que os arquivos `ma.flexslider.js` e `jquery-ui.js` fazem uso.

Comment: Tens a certeza que o uglify não junta o ficheiro por estar minificado? Eu diria que é problema de path ou outro... tens isso no Github para eu poder testar?

Comment: Pior que não tenho no github @Sergio, é um projeto Magento.

Comment: Agora vendo aqui, ele está adicionando corretamente, acho que o problema é sintax mesmo @Sergio

Comment: Ok, nesse caso e se funciona coloca uma resposta indicando o que estava errado e como resolveste. Assim pode ser que seja útil a outros.

Comment: Blz, mesmo assim vlw pela disposição em ajuda!

Comment: Usar uma [task apenas para concatenar](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) não seria melhor do que usar uma task com dois papéis?

Comment: Psé o lance é esse, mas primeiro eu tenho que minificar os que não estão minnificados :D

Answer (score 1):

Execute a task `concat` antes do `uglify`.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat